# Unity 2D: How to put entire game in the safe area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Unity 2D game and I'm looking for help on how to make sure the entire game only displays in the safe area on both iOS and Android.

There's no shortage of tutorials on how to put Canvas elements inside the safe area, but I'd like my entire game to fit in there. Is there an automatic way to do this in Unity? Or perhaps a way to set the camera bounds to the safe area? What's the best way? Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution?